# Script Bash & Batch - Resolution in Wine & Windows Registry For Some Games

Tags: bash, batch-file, registry, screen-resolution

well this time , i have the dunno how to make in Bash and Batch scripts

1 - Detect the current resolution

2 - Write in the Registry Key that Resolution

3 - I Dont know all resolutions in "dword" , someone can help me , with all resolutions , of any screen , 2:1 , 4:3 , 5:4 , 11:6 , 15:9 , 16:9 , 16:10 , 25:16 , 60:29 , 72:35 , any

Okey now , for Example , with Wine under "No Windows S.O" , in "Bash" script . its more practical use something like this ->

A - Obtain the Current Resolution under Linux for Example ->

```
echo `xrandr --current | grep current | awk '{print $8}'` >> Resolution1
echo `xrandr --current | grep current | awk '{print $10}'` >> Resolution2
cat Resolution2 | sed -i 's/,//g' Resolution2
P1Resolution=$(cat Resolution1)
P2Resolution=$(cat Resolution2)
rm Resolution1 Resolution2
echo "$P1Resolution"'x'"$P2Resolution" >> Resolution
Resolution=$(cat Resolution)
rm Resolution
```

B - Write a Registry File , for Example for "Warcraft 3" or "Ragnarok Classic International"

Warcraft 3 :->

```
if      [ $Resolution = "640x480" ]; then
echo "REGEDIT4" >> video.reg
echo "" >> video.reg
echo "[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Blizzard Entertainment\Warcraft III\Video]" >> video.reg
echo '"resHEIGHT"=dword:000001e0' >> video.reg
echo '"resWIDTH"=dword:00000280' >> video.reg

# Add ResolutionRate
echo '"ResolutionRatehrate"=dword:00000046' >> video.reg
regedit -s video.reg

    elif    [ $Resolution = "800x600" ]; then
echo "REGEDIT4" >> video.reg
echo "" >> video.reg
echo "[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Blizzard Entertainment\Warcraft III\Video]" >> video.reg
echo '"resHEIGHT"=dword:00000258' >> video.reg
echo '"resWIDTH"=dword:00000320' >> video.reg

# Add ResolutionRate
echo '"ResolutionRatehrate"=dword:00000046' >> video.reg
regedit -s video.reg

    elif    [ $Resolution = "1024x768" ]; then
echo "REGEDIT4" >> video.reg
echo "" >> video.reg
echo "[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Blizzard Entertainment\Warcraft III\Video]" >> video.reg
echo '"resHEIGHT"=dword:00000300' >> video.reg
echo '"resWIDTH"=dword:00000400' >> video.reg

# Add ResolutionRate
echo '"ResolutionRatehrate"=dword:00000046' >> video.reg
regedit -s video.reg
rm -rf video.reg
else
    echo "Unknow Resolution"
fi
```

Well Now with Ragnarok International :->

```
if          [ $Resolution = "640x480" ]; then
echo "REGEDIT4" >> video.reg
echo "" >> video.reg
echo "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Gravity Soft\Ragnarok]" >> video.reg
echo '"HEIGHT="=dword:000001e0' >> video.reg
echo '"WIDTH"=dword:00000280' >> video.reg
regedit -s video.reg

    elif    [ $Resolution = "800x600" ]; then
echo "REGEDIT4" >> video.reg
echo "" >> video.reg
echo "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Gravity Soft\Ragnarok]" >> video.reg
echo '"HEIGHT"=dword:00000258' >> video.reg
echo '"WIDTH"=dword:00000320' >> video.reg
regedit -s video.reg

    elif    [ $Resolution = "1024x768" ]; then
echo "REGEDIT4" >> video.reg
echo "" >> video.reg
echo "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Gravity Soft\Ragnarok]" >> video.reg
echo '"HEIGHT"=dword:00000300' >> video.reg
echo '"WIDTH"=dword:00000400' >> video.reg
regedit -s video.reg
rm -rf video.reg

else
    echo "Unknow Resolution"
fi
```

Okey that works fine in Bash , now in Batch , from where i can obtain the "Current Resolution" under Native "Windows" ???

Part of the Batch Script , are be something like :

```
Warcraft 3 :->

@echo off

color A
title Automatic Resolution Setup

set key1=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Blizzard Entertainment\
set key2=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Blizzard Entertainment\Warcraft III
set key3=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Blizzard Entertainment\Warcraft III\Video

reg delete "%key1%" /f
reg add "%key1%" /f
reg add "%key2%" /f
reg add "%key3%" /f
reg add "%key3%" /t REG_DWORD /v reswidth /d %CURRENT_WIDTH% /f
reg add "%key3%" /t REG_DWORD /v reshieght /d %CURRENT_HEIGHT% /f
```

Ragnarok International :->

```
@echo off
color A
title Automatic Resolution Setup
set key=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Gravity Soft\Ragnarok
reg delete "%key%" /f
reg add "%key% /f
reg add "%key%" /t REG_DWORD /v WIDTH /d %CURRENT_WIDTH% /f
reg add "%key%" /t REG_DWORD /v HEIGHT /d %CURRENT_HEIGHT% /f
```

I need to know what are all possible resolutions , I just Know the Follows ->

```
#640x480  -> "(res)WIDTH"=dword:00000280 "(res)HEIGHT"=dword:000001e0
#800x600  -> "(res)WIDTH"=dword:00000320 "(res)HEIGHT"=dword:00000258
#1024x768 -> "(res)WIDTH"=dword:00000400 "(res)HEIGHT"=dword:00000300
#1280×768 –> "(res)WIDTH"=dword:00000500 "(res)HEIGHT"=dword:00000300 
#1280×800 –> "(res)WIDTH"=dword:00000500 "(res)HEIGHT"=dword:00000320 
#1360×768 –> "(res)WIDTH"=dword:00000550 "(res)HEIGHT"=dword:00000300 
#1440×900 –> "(res)WIDTH"=dword:000005A0 "(res)HEIGHT"=dword:00000384
```

Well , how i can get the values for "height" and "width" under natives windows , using a "Batch Script" for determinate the current resolution ???

Someone can help me with my scripts plz ???

Comment: you should check out if you can use _wmic_: `wmic os get version`

Comment: +1 for Ragnarok :) I think it's better if you create a PowerShell script instead. You'll find it so difficult to parse output with batch files. You can also install UNIX-like environments like Cygwin to make it possible to run shell scripts instead.

Answer (score 1):

Under Cygwin (or possible some lighter environments as well) this would give you your resolution:

```
#!/bin/bash

ScreenWidth=$(wmic desktopmonitor get screenwidth | grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+')
ScreenHeight=$(wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight | grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+')
Resolution="${ScreenWidth}x${ScreenHeight}"

...
```

Credits to Endoro for suggesting the command `wmic`.

Answer (score 1):

The following will define environment variables `ScreenHeight` and `ScreenWidth`

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'wmic desktopmonitor get ScreenHeight^,ScreenWidth /value'
) do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set %%B
```

The extra FOR /F loop is to eliminate `<Carriage Return>` artifacts that FOR /F introduces when it processes the unicode output of WMIC.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with my Windows 8/64. I get `ScreenWidth=`. I must use `wmic path cim_videocontroller get CurrentHorizontalResolution,CurrentVerticalResolution /format:list` to grab the Resolution.

Comment: @Endoro - interesting. PATH CIM_VIDEOCONTROLLER works on my Win 7 and my virtual XP also. Presumeably /VALUE works for you just as well as /FORMAT:LIST. Both give the same output for me.